# asp.net ObjectDataSource error handling

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

I have objectdatasource and I am trying to find a way to capture the error that is thrown by the SELECT method.

anyone idea how it can be done?

Page level error handling is preferred, not capturing error at the application_error in global.asax

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        ds.Selected += new ObjectDataSourceStatusEventHandler(ds_Selected);
    }

    void ds_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {

        }
    }
```