# Error handling in ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

Thanks to the help :[asp.net ObjectDataSource error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498211/asp-net-objectdatasource-error-handling)

Don't work for me !

My page **.aspx** contains :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblErreur" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCollab" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAll" TypeName="Dao.DaoCollaborateur"  OnSelected="odsCollab_Selected" >
 </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

My page **.aspx.cs** contains :

```
 protected void odsCollab_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
       if (e.Exception != null)
       {
                lblErreur.Text = String.Format("Une erreur d'accès à la base ({0}) s'est produite sur la page ", e.Exception.Message);
                e.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
```

}

My method  **GetAll ()**.... simple as possible contain:

```
public static List<Collaborateur> GetAll()
{  

       throw new Exception("Test exception");
}
```

"The exception was unhandled by user code" ... in GetAll () method

I want to manage the database connection

What is missing to me?
Thanks in advance